# $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/\frak{a}$ is an $k$-algebra of finite type?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $k$ be a field and $\frak{a}$$\subset k[x_1,\dots,a_n]$ be an ideal.

Can someone explain to me why $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/\frak{a}$ is an $k$-algebra **of finite type**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My definition of "$k$-algebra of finite type" is precisely $A \simeq k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]/\mathfrak a$, so I'm afraid I can't tell you more. In some sense this means that $A$ has finitely many generators (as a $k$-algebra), i.e. every element of $A$ can be expressed as a polynomial with coefficients in $k$ in the variables $x_n$'s (although there are relations between those variables, i.e. the elements of $\mathfrak a$.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Yes, and, also, since $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is Noetherian, every ideal $\mathfrak a$ is finitely-generated, so that ideal of "relations" is also "finite".